# small function to append values to three lists

Tags: python, function, pycharm

Function is working properly but lists are not updated. When I print them its always print new added contacts it means when I run function again previous added data is gone new details store to lists

```
 names = []
 address = []
 telephone = []


    def new_contact():

       names.append(input("Enter Name"))



       address.append(input("Enter Address"))



      telephone.append(input("Enter Telephone Number"))

      print("New Contact Created ")

      print(names)

      print(address)
```

new_contact()

print(telephone[0])

Comment: Is this the only code? Post complete code, if not.

Comment: This code _defines_ the function `new_contact()` but never _calls_ it.  Show us the code that calls it.

Comment: Is this Python 2 or Python 3?  If it's Python 2, you'll want to use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`.

Comment: @JohnGordon its python 3

Comment: @JohnGordon does function like this can modify outside lists  is that the problem i used global one time its also not worked

Comment: @Austin i edited with complete code its actually little code i'm trying to learn python with self studying

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend object-oriented programming.

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, address, telephone):
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
        self.telephone = telephone

def new_contact():
    n = input("Enter name")
    a = input("Enter address")
    t = input("Enter telephone")
    return Person(n, a, t)

people = []
people.append(new_contact())
```

Comment: i will try it and let you know how its work thank you very much

Comment: every time run this code details add to list[0 ] place previously added details are missing

Answer (score 0):

```
names = []
address = []
telephone = []
def new_contact():

  names.append(input("Enter Name"))

  address.append(input("Enter Address"))

  telephone.append(input("Enter Telephone Number"))

  print("New Contact Created ")
  print(names)
  print(address)

new_contact()
```

Comment: This essentially doesn't do anything except call the function as the OP was told to do in the comments, with zero explanation. As such, it's a low quality answer.

Comment: this program run once and store data and second time when programe runs its overwrites data _listname_[0] always store data to frist point in the list

Comment: @KesharaHulangamuwa no this will append as lists declared are global and append is being used to append a value to list.